# WPF DLL builds correctly but causes errors when used

Tags: wpf, xaml, dll, resourcedictionary

I'm in Visual Studio 2017, using .Net 4.6.1

I have made a library (in Project A) of WPF styles, controls, converters etc for use when building applications. The idea is that if there is a corporate branding change, we can republish the library and all the applications referencing it will be re-branded.

Project A has no errors or warnings and builds correctly to make a .dll file.

When I come to reference the .DLL in Project B however, the xaml that references some of the .DLL components gives the `Loading designer... You can continue working while the designer is loading in the background` message forever. When I try to start Project B, It tells me it is in break mode, with a `System.StackOverflowException` and that's that.

I have tried adding and removing lines in the app.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Colours.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Brushes.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Text.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

and doing so gives me a hint, perhaps in that only some references (or maybe having too many references?) cause the designer to fail, but I'm having a hell of a time trying to find what's going on.

Do you have any idea how I might go about debugging this problem, given that Project A, where the problem appears to be, builds correctly? For instance any tips or tricks or extra tools that might identify problems at design time?

Alternatively, any advice on how to check everything in Project B is as it should be would be welcome. I have checked all the references, namespaces and resource dictionaries and confident that the syntax is correct, but maybe there's a gotcha that I could have missed?

Comment: A `StackOverflowException` indicates that you have some kind of infinite loop somewhere. These won't be discovered at compile time. You need to provide more details for anyone to be able to help you out here.

Comment: Sounds like there might be something in Project A that recurses or loops infinitely. I'd look over the C# code in Project A. If I didn't see anything suspicious, I'd comment out all the C# code except for boilerplate stuff like InitializeComponent(), and have all the converters just return null. See if it loads OK. If it does, start uncommenting code until it breaks again.

Comment: P.S. I'd also identify all the places in the code that absolutely, obviously, can't possibly be the problem, and look at those first.

Comment: I'll give those a try. It is possible that in my attempts to separate out all the different components into different dictionaries, I have a reference loop in the merged dictionaries - would that cause the overflow? So Dic1.xaml uses Dic2.xaml which uses Dic3.xaml which uses Dic1.xaml... I'll check for such things and get back. There's very little C# code used, but I'll clear out everything but the styles then re-add one by one... looks like it'll be the long way to find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this, it turns out is one of those annoying problems which you leave for a weekend and when you return it has changed its look. I came back and could no longer get the stack overflow error.

The error reported was a failure of the UserControl in Project A to find one of the resources built into the same project. I was able to fix this by changing the references in the Merged dictionary from standard to [Pack URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf) format (the local path references only work when viewed in the project itself - they fail in the DLL). From this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Buttons.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Gradients.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Text.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

to this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Buttons.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Gradients.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFLibrary;component/Styles/Text.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

From this I learnt - Local references only work locally in a DLL between resource dictionaries; if you wish to use a UserControl from the DLL, you have to use the pack format. In future I will use Pack URIs everywhere that they do not cause a syntax error!